# Access mdb file, the DB keeps trying to connect to a remote server

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I have to change some code for one of my client. Now they have given me the mdb file and the sql database. What is happening is every time I try to open the mdb file it tries to connect to their sql server and I cant find a way to change this. I cant even get in. it gives an error saying ODBC - connection to server failed.

Is there a way to change the db connection? I cannot access any code at this point and no other option is available on the Access. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Open the Access document while keeping the Shift key pressed.  This will prevent scripts from running, and you should be able to trouble shoot from there.